# Transition and mouseover

Tags: javascript, css, menu, transition

Working with JavaScript it seems there may be an issue where transition causes an issue with the closing of a menu. In this MWE the menu on the left opens as it should by either clicking the menu icon or through mouseover. It also closes properly with mouseout. However, when attempting to close by clicking the close icon there is some discrepancy: it works erratically. Could this be due to the transition effect? It seems to close properly when the transition is removed. How could the transition be retained while also making the menu close properly both by mouseout and clicking the relevant icon?

Thanks.

MVE:

```
<html><head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <style> 
  #title {text-align:right}
  #menu {display:block;height:100%;width:180px; position:fixed;top:0;left:-120px; overflow:visible;background:lightgrey;transition:.3s}
  #menuicon, #closeicon {position:absolute;top:1em;left:150px;cursor:pointer}
  #closeicon {display:none}
 </style> 
 <script> 
  function menutoggle(x) {
   if (x) {
    document.getElementById('menu').style.left = '0';
    document.getElementById('menuicon').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('closeicon').style.display = 'block';
   } else {
    document.getElementById('menu').style.left = '-120px'; 
    document.getElementById('menuicon').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('closeicon').style.display = 'none';
   }
  } 
 </script> 
</head>
<body> 
<div id="menu" onmouseover="menutoggle(1)" onmouseout="menutoggle()"> 
 <span id="closeicon" onclick="menutoggle()">X</span>
 <span id="menuicon" onclick="menutoggle(1)">=</span>
</div> 
<p id="title">Title</p>
</body></html>``
```

Comment: When you close the menu with the close button, the `mouseout` probably also fires closing the menu again which can cause trouble when having transitions.

Comment: That seems to be correctly observed, yes.